# How to pass size_t parameter to function by reference and get the result back in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a simple hash function in C, and given most of my knowledge of programming is in Java, I need some help please. I defined size_t with the following typedef statement:

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

I then proceeded to define a simple; really a place holder for a hash function.

```
size_t hash(char const *input) {

    const int ret_size = 32;
    size_t ret = 0x555555;
    const int per_char = 7;

    while (*input) {
            ret ^= *input++;
            ret = ((ret << per_char) | (ret >> (ret_size - per_char)));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I then used the function in the main() section of my code as follows:

```
 size_t myInput = 546;
 size_t myHash;
 ...
 myHash=hash(&myInput);
```

But I get a compiler error stating:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'hash' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
error, forbidden warning: tos1.c:52
```

What am I doing wrong please? How can I fix it?

The feedback was right on point and fixed my issue. I'll mark the comment as answer as soon as I am allowed and thanks.

Comment: How are you expecting your `hash` function to know how many bytes to hash?

Comment: Why are you redefining `size_t`?

Comment: The hash function you defined takes a string. `546` is a number, not a string.

Comment: Guys I do not know C that much. If you would advise how to fix with a short explanation. I did the best I could, and admit the code is wrong.

Comment: @user3326293 In Java, `546` is not a string either.

Comment: 1) "size_t" is a C built-in. Don't redefine it. 2) hash() takes a character pointer (i.e. "string") as an argument, and you're trying to pass it the number 546.

Comment: this line: `size_t myInput = 546;`  should be something more like: `char myInput[] = "546";`  or `char *myInput = "546";`

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `size_t` is not a built-in type. It's defined in `stddef.h` and `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Well, yes, but that distinction is probably beyond our questioner for the moment.

Comment: @melpomene-You are right, I should know primitive types better. My point was I do not know size_t in C. As you can see the problem in my code was not just that; I also redefined size_t by mistake. I have to say I enjoy writing C code, and as soon as I have more time, I'll review the relevant texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to define `size_t`; it should already be defined.

The problem is that your function definition takes a `const char *` parameter, but you're calling it with a value of type `size_t *`; the types are not compatible.

Your input should be a string of some sort, like

```
char input[] = "This is a test";
...
myHash = hash( input );
```

Remember that C strings are simply sequences of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte; they are *stored* as arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for wide characters), but not all arrays of `char` contain a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function with arguments of any type, you can write the prototypes to look like, for example, `memcpy()` and `memset()`.  That is,

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint_fast32_t hash_t;
hash_t hash( const void* src, size_t size )
{
  const uint8_t* p = (const uint8_t*)src;
  /* We can dereference p now and do pointer arithmetic with it. */
  /* … */
}

extern struct data_t foo;
extern const char* message;

hash_t value = hash( &foo, sizeof(foo) );
hash_t string_hash = hash( message, strlen(message) );
```